# TableViewController not properly deleting cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

My `tableviewcontroller` is behaving improperly. Lets say I add 2 objects to it: `dog` and `cat`.

```
 - dog
 - cat
```

Then I delete cat.

```
 - dog
```

Then I add a third (at this point second) object `bird`. The cell will populate with `cat` instead of bird. Bird ends up not being stored anywhere and my list results in this:

```
 - dog 
 - cat
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause of such behavior? I'm not looking for a specific error in my code as the code is too much to show. I'm hoping you guys might know what I should take a look at to fix this. If you guys want to see some of my code either way, let me know. Thanks.

edit: So I had the console print out all the objects in the array whenever something was deleted. The objects are properly being added/deleted into the array, so it seems my cells are not populating with data properly.

Here is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        Employee* tempEmployee = [[[EmployeeStore store] employees] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString* label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"N. %@   P. %@", tempEmployee.name, tempEmployee.pin];
        [[cell textLabel] setText: label];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here is what I use to delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        NSMutableArray* employees = [[EmployeeStore store] employees];
        [[EmployeeStore store] removeEmployee:[employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Here is `removeEmployee:` from my EmployeeStore class that is called in the above method:

```
-(void) removeEmployee:(Employee*)e{
    [context deleteObject:e];
    [employees removeObject:e];
}
```

edit 2: My application is utilizing core data to save the table entries. When I close the app, and run it again, the error fixes itself (meaning its loading from the context properly). So it goes from

```
 - dog 
 - cat
```

to the intended:

```
 - dog
 - bird
```

Seems to be improper updating?

Comment: Please post the code of deleting the cell & displaying the cell(cellForRowAtIndexPath method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    Employee* tempEmployee = [[[EmployeeStore store] employees] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"N. %@   P. %@", tempEmployee.name, tempEmployee.pin];
    [[cell textLabel] setText: label];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. I see now why it was doing so. Thank you so much. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Move the following code outside of the if condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
  Employee* tempEmployee = [[[EmployeeStore store] employees] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString* label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"N. %@   P. %@", tempEmployee.name, tempEmployee.pin];
  [[cell textLabel] setText: label];
```

Simple error in your code : You set the `cell` text only if a new `cell` was allocated, not when a `cell` is reused.